# what does O("info") mean in the code below in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, parameters

I read this from a book about passing ajax html form to check username with code like this:

```
function checkUser(user) {
    if (user.value == "") {
        O('info').innerHTML = ''
        return
    }
    //lots of code on ajaxrequest....
}
```

In HTML:

```
<form>
    input of username password etc .....
    <span id='info'><span>
</form>
```

Basically the code I showed was clearing the span with `id='info'` if user input without value.

My question is:

1. What does that uppercase o or zero0 (`O('info')` or `0('info')`) mean? is it just JavaScript??
2. I didn't read any predefined function there, so if it is just a function passing `'info'` as argument, how did it managed to pass it without `getElementByID()`?

THX

Comment: They probably made a function `O` that returns an element by its ID.

Comment: It calls a function called `O` that is presumably defined or described in the book, its nothing built into the language or browser.

Comment: @phiter thx for the edit ;)

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I think i found the answer. You guys being really helpful and quick in response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> what does that uppercase o or zero0 ('info') means in that js code?

It's a variable name, pointing to a variable holding a function.

> i didn't read any predefined function there, so if it is just a function passing 'info' as argument, how did it managed to pass it without getElementByID()?

Somewhere, although not in the code you shared, there is some code that defines `O`.

Answer (score -1):

i think O stands for the function:

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

to get an DOM Object and setting its property innerHTML to empty string

Answer (score -1):

Probably this function was used in the book somewhere. This is an 'alias' for an existing function that they wrote to illustrate 'working with aliasses'. Just a guess :)

```
function O(str) {
    return document.getElementByID(str);
}
```